# VBA Autofilter (Text Filters) With Multiple Criteria of "begin with"

Tags: vba, excel

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F_Item").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("ca*", "inc*", "ps*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I am trying to filter column with multiple criteria using array, the condition is to filter the values which starts with `ca`, or starts with `inc`, or start with `ps`.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F_Item").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=ca*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=inc*"
```

It's working this way, but its limited to search for two conditions only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub WildAutofilter()
    Dim data As Range, c As Collection
    Dim v As String, i As Long, ary
    Set data = Range("A1:A23")
    Set c = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
        For i = 2 To 23
            v = Cells(i, 1).Value
            If Left(v, 2) = "ps" Or Left(v, 2) = "ca" Or Left(v, 3) = "inc" Then
                c.Add v, CStr(v)
            End If
        Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

    ReDim ary(0 To c.Count - 1)
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        ary(i - 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next i

    With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$23")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=(ary), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Will produce:

[image]

Comment: Thanks dude, Its working for me, Nice approach :) But I was wondering its not possible to do it one line, like filtering with the help of *

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Advance filter

```
Range("C3:C20").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Range("D3:D6"), Unique:=False
```