# Excel VBA Autofilter - Multiple Criteria of "begin with"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, ms-office

I'm using vba to autofilter a list in Excel 2010, and would like to autofilter a list based on 3 or more "begins with" criteria (ie. "a*", "b*", "c*"). Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, you can only have two "begins with" criteria using Operator:=xlOr.

The accepted answer for [VBA Autofilter (Text Filters) With Multiple Criteria of "begin with"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413433/vba-autofilter-text-filters-with-multiple-criteria-of-begin-with) looks like it would work. However looping through every single item in the list and adding the values to an array, then autofiltering an exact match to those items is cumbersome. Especially with very large lists.

Is there a better way to autofilter more than two "begins with" criteria?

Comment: Can't you do this with [advanced filter](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b#bmconcepts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: Accepted answer, but OP is using Gary's answer previously mentioned in the question**

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we want to see items beginning with either  *A*, *D*, or *M*.

Running this macro:

```
Sub ThreeWay()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2:A25")

    For Each r In rng
        v = Left(r.Value, 1)
        If v = "A" Or v = "D" Or v = "M" Then
            r.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

will produce:
[image]

***Note:***

- this is a "filter-by-hand" rather than a true AutoFilter
- if you absolutely must have an AutoFilter, then use the method in my old Post

Comment: This is good, thanks! However, I need to use autofilter as the user needs to be able to manipulate and sort and continue filtering the data after the macro is run.

Comment: @NateBergeron  The only other option I can think of is to use a *helper* column in the worksheet and have the macro manipulate that column.

Comment: OK, I think I'll just use the method you have in the other question. I'll mark this question as the answer with an edit to mention I'm using the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just read everything first in into an array, this is quit fast.
2. Use the array to perform some logic on it.
3. Pierce every value out of the array you don't want to be shown by your filter.
4. If this is done you have an array with values you want to display.

---

```
Sub filter()

'ie. "a*", "b*", "c*").
'1 <==
filter_0 = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A2").End(-4121)).Value
filter_00 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(filter_0)

'2 <==
For i = LBound(filter_00) To UBound(filter_00)
    If Left(filter_00(i), 1) = "a" Then
    ElseIf Left(filter_00(i), 1) = "b" Then
    ElseIf Left(filter_00(i), 1) = "c" Then
    Else   '3 <==
        filter_00(i) = ""
    End If
Next i

'4 <==
With ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A1"), Range("A2").End(-4121))
    .AutoFilter FIELD:=1, Criteria1:=Array(filter_00), Operator:=7
End With

End Sub
```