# Short-cut for Text Filter column with 2 criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, filter, keyboard-shortcuts, ribbon

I need to use **Filter + Text Filter + Contains + and + Contains** custom filter a lot in my sheet. But it takes many time to come to that line.

I would like to:

Have a **Short-Cut** to directly go to that "Contains+and+Contains" option,

P.S: As I'll always search for different combination of words within a cell to find the best match, this link also did not help me. [VBA Autofilter (Text Filters) With Multiple Criteria of "begin with"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413433/vba-autofilter-text-filters-with-multiple-criteria-of-begin-with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a macro that shows the desired "Contains+Contains" form and then set a shortcut key to it, and you can even add a custom button in the Quick-Access Toolbar that points to it.

Supposing the drop-down of the filter you want to manipulate is at cell `A1` of `"Sheet1"` (adjust to your own layout):

```
Sub showContains()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")              ' <-- customize to your case
        .Activate
        .Range("A1").Select                ' <-- customize to your case
        Application.SendKeys "%{DOWN}fa"
    End With

    ' The line below will setup key `F12` to invoke again the macro, so that
    ' you need to launch it regularly only once, and then via F12...
    Application.OnKey "{F12}", "showContains"
End Sub
```

To set a button in the Quick-Access Toolbar that lauches your macro, do this in Excel's GUI:

```
Right-click the Ribbon --> Customize Quick-Access-Toolbar --> more commands
--> choose commands from(macros) --> select the macro showContains.
```

**Some explanation**

After first selecting the header cell that has the filter, `Application.SendKeys "%{DOWN}fa"` simulates the following keystrokes:

- `Alt + DownArrow` opens the filter dialog embedded in the selected cell
- `f` which is the hotkey for the `Text Filters` menu item
- `a` which is the hotkey for the `Contains` menu item

If as per your request, you want to go directly to the second "contains" item, you can modify that keystroke pattern to this:

```
Application.SendKeys "%{DOWN}fa{Tab}{Tab}C{Tab}"
```

Finally, to have the macro "guess" which field you want to open the dialog for, well that's not feasible with one macro. What you can do eventually is to make this sub parametric with the range, and make a different `(macro/shortcut-key`) for each field.

Comment: Hi @A.S.H **firstly** thank you for this great answer. That works perfectly except selecting the second **"Contains"** option. Is there any possibility to upgrade this code to also select the second **"contains"** one?


**Secondly,** how that **"%{DOWN}fa"** thing works and what are the other SendKeys options for that, where can I find it? I just googled this "%{DOWN}fa" one but didn't find nothing.


**Thirdly,** what else can be done for **multiple different columns?** Should I create new macros for each one or Can I define all of them into one macro or what is the best suggestion?

Comment: According to my first question on my answer above, I _don't know how_ (_or even if it's possible_) but, **if we can define** the keyboard movement as: **"Tab+Tab+12 times Down+Tab"** it will also choose second Contains in the custom filter that occurs after your macro.

Comment: @Mertinc see my additional explanations above.

Comment: A.S.H, you are amazing mate. That'll help me a lot. Thanks a lot. 
My last question is just to understand that **SendKeys** function more (to be able to change that Contains option with others without having trouble).
I see that you mostly use the first letter of the options that we would like to choose. But in case of multiple options that starting with the same letter, what should be done? for instance in this case: 1- does not equal 2- does not begin with 3- does not contain. How to select their letters for macro? 
And can you suggest me any link for look at that thing?

Comment: @Mertinc  Thanks for the compliment :). Well that's pretty easy in fact. First, the `SendKeys` function is explained in detail [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821075.aspx). Notice that the `{...}` pattern is used for special keys, and the `%` is for the `Alt` key. Second, whenever you open a menu in a windows app, you see for each item some *underligned* character that represents its shortcut. You can investigate the sequence in Excel and then encode it using `SendKeys`.