# Application.SendKeys macro runs too slow. How to improve it's speed?

Tags: vba, performance, excel, time

[Thanks to A.S.H I am using this below code to open ***Contains and Contains Custom Filter*** on my Table:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428753/short-cut-for-text-filter-column-with-2-criteria-in-excel)

```
Sub showContains()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, LastRowsOfTable As Long

    With Application
 .ScreenUpdating = False
 .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 .EnableEvents = False
    End With

Set ws1 = Sheet1
ws1.Activate
ws1.Range("C1").Select       ' <-- customize to your case
LastRowsOfTable = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = LastRowsOfTable - 25
        Application.SendKeys "%{DOWN}fa{Tab}{Tab}C{Tab}"

'Select C1 => click ALT+Down Arrow => text filters => contains => and contains

 With Application
     .ScreenUpdating = True
     .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
     .EnableEvents = True
         End With
    End Sub
```

Now my question is, although I disable Application properties at the beginning, it still runs the macro step by step, same as if I didn't disable Application properties. And it's too slow. (My table has 8000 rows but I don't think it's because of this reason.)

**How can I improve the code to run faster?**

P.S: When I try to screen it's speed with:

```
Dim starttime As Double
starttime = Timer
.
.
above codes
.
.
MsgBox Format(Timer - starttime, "00.00") & "seconds"
End Sub
```

Msgbox just shows me 00.36 seconds kind of short time but it doesn't open my Contains and Contains custom filter. So it seems like it's working too fast but actually it doesn't run anything. (if I add this timer codes)

**Normally macro runs within 5-7 seconds.** Which is unacceptable for this case.

Comment: I always suggest adding .Cursor = xlWait with the other applications (change to .Cursor = xlDefault at the end). This can sometimes drastically improve performance.

Comment: I straight forward tried but nothing has changed @dwirony.

Comment: Do you have menu animations enabled in Windows?  i.e. do your menus "fade in" and "fade out", etc?  If so, that might be slowing the macro (and everything else) down.  You could try googling "disable windows animations" if you think that's a possible cause.

Comment: Generally I don't have that kind of problem, this is particular one I think. But I'll try searching for this issue as well thanks YowE3K.

Comment: @YowE3K https://superuser.com/questions/547832/disable-excel-2013-cell-animation I found that kind of link for your suggestion but now I'm afraid to disable something that I might not want to disable. What do you think, should I really give it a try?

Comment: Disabling animations is a **good** idea in my opinion - I get sick and tired of having to wait while menus fade/zoom in and out.  Sure, it's "pretty", but I want to use my computer to **do** things, not to amuse me.

Comment: Unfortunately disabling windows animations didn't help me as well.

Comment: What is the sendkeys supposed to do ? And then you do it without sendkeys. It's slow AND very uncertain to achieve your goal, that's why programmers never use it unless they cannot otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, SendKeys was my only solution. Can you please check the link I provided within my question. There you can find detailed explanation.