# VBA Autofilter With Multiple Criteria of "begin with"

Tags: excel, vba

New to Marco and VBA. Tried searching for a solution to vba autofilter with multiple criteria of being with but I only found so solutions that flitered out my entry and leave the other results. I a unable to find anything that just show me the results that begins with what I want.

E.g. I want to find all items that beings with ABC, 123 and 789

So for ABC123, 345ddd,123kss,789000. I should only see ABC123345ddd,123kss in my results

I will need to compare all data in a range (a:a) in a column and not a known number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Autofilter (Text Filters) With Multiple Criteria of "begin with"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413433/vba-autofilter-text-filters-with-multiple-criteria-of-begin-with)

Comment: Thanks. I tired that solution but I encounter a runtime error 9 subscript out of range. I need to compare the whole range A:A instead of only some fields so I changed for I to A to A.

Comment: Please [edit] and include in your your question: Exactly the code *you* tried. Which error you get and in which line. And give a good example or screenshots of your original data and how your result would look like. Reading [ask] and [mcve] might help.